# Password Protect Pages Not Working

Tags: pages, password

I recently switched to a new theme, and it does not seem to have the functionality to password-protect individual pages. It only displays "Protected" in page title, but still shows the content without prompting for password. How can I enable this manually? I tried to add (if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) { into a custom page template, but it didn't work. Please help me with correct code here or some other solution. Thanks a lot!

```
 <?php 
// Template Name: Password Protected 
get_header(); ?>



<!-- Margin -->
<div class="margin-2">

<div class="spacing-40"></div>

<!-- Single full Page Container-->
    <div id="single-full">

    <h1 class="entry-header"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <div class="spacing-20"></div>

        <div class="entry wide-entry">





<?php 

                        $my_postid = get_page( $page_id );//This is page id or post id
                        $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
                        $content = $content_post->post_content;
                        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                        //$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
                        echo $content; 
                        ?>

        </div>

    </div>
<!-- Single full Page Container-->

<!-- Margin -->
<div id="widget-container">
    <?php
    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
        || !dynamic_sidebar(2) ) : 
    endif;

    ?>
</div>

<!-- Margin -->

<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="spacing-20"></div>
</div>



<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="spacing-40"></div>
</div>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace **all** of this:

```
$my_postid = get_page( $page_id );//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
//$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
```

...with this:

```
the_content();
```